# Seletor CSS/jQuery para uma coluna da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Existe algum seletor CSS ou do jQuery que pegue uma coluna de uma tabela (cada `td` da coluna)?

Ou, caso não haja um seletor simples que consiga fazer isso, dá pra fazer com pouco código em jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: pode ser mais expecifico? por que não usar uma classe e pegar essa clasee através de CSS ou JQuery?

Comment: Porque queria aprender um modo generico.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se nenhum dos TDs possuir um `colspan` então é possível fazer isso usando a pseudo-classe `:nth-child`:

Exemplo para selecionar todos os terceiros TDs:

```
table td:nth-child(3) {
    /* estilo */
}
```

[Referência na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

**Suporte dos navegadores:**

O jQuery não possui problemas com isso, funciona nos browseres suportados pela biblioteca.

Mas em termos de CSS, funciona a partir do IE 9. Você poderia usar o jQuery no IE 8 ou menor, para atribuir o CSS que quiser usando essa pseudo-classe, ou então, usar o seguinte CSS que usa a pseudo-classe `:first-child` e o operador de proximidade (chamado de [`Adjacent sibling selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)):

```
table td:first-child + td + td {
    /* estilo */
}
```

Comment: +1 Eu estava tentando fazer com `:eq`, mas não funcionou, mas o seu método funciona. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/HzT49/) (Nota: é bom frisar que esse índice é baseado em `1`, não em `0`)

Comment: @mgibsonbr: você quer dizer que o índice do `:eq` é zero based, não é?

Comment: Sim o `:eq` é. Mas pelo fiddle acima, o `:nth-child` é one based.

Comment: A outra resposta me preocupou, pois preciso usar em navegadores antigos. Se souber alguma alternativa pode acrescentar a resposta?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Se você fizer via jQuery - em vez de via CSS - ele cuida desses detalhes pra você, não? (simulando as funcionalidades que o navegador não suporta nativamente)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @Miguel Angelo vai resolver seu problema.

Porém, como é CSS3
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Você não poderá usar em navegadores antigos.

Você poderia usar uma classe pra definir uma coluna especifica ex:

```
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td class="Coluna1">Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="Coluna1">Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Após isso você pode pegar essa coluna por CSS ou por Jquery

CSS

```
.Coluna1{
//Codigo aqui
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.Coluna1)
```

Comment: Valeu a intenção, mas assim eu já sei. Era justamente pra conhecer algum modo mais genérico que possa ser aplicado rapidamente em qualquer página.